# DBCC Checkident doesn't work for reseeding tables

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to reseed all of my tables. I delete all the values from them and then run this query:

But then when I populate this database again, id starts from the maximal id of the deleted entries. Why doesn't it work?

UPDATE:

delete queries:

```
delete from Car;
delete from Detail;
delete from Owner;
```

and then

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Car', RESEED, 0);
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Detail', RESEED, 0);
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Owner', RESEED, 0);
```

Both Car and Detail tables has user_id foreign key which points to the User's id column.

Comment: If you want to delete all rows and reset the `id` value you can just use `truncate`. That said this works for me `create table Car(Id int identity); insert into Car default values; insert into Car default values; select * from Car; delete from Car;DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Car', RESEED, 0);insert into Car default values;select * from Car; drop table Car`

Comment: Trancate doesn't work for those tables which has foreign keys and both Car and Detail tables have foreign keys

Comment: If you're going to wipe all the tables clean, why don't you create your script so that it drops the constraints and re-creates them? Or just drops the tables and re-creates them?

Comment: Can you post the full script that deletes the data and reseeds the tables?  What you've posted should work, assuming the tables are in the correct schema.

Comment: That's it, it's very simlpe but I can't understand why it doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Except for any other errors, script, or settings, etc that are not described, there shouldn't be any reason why this shouldn't work. Here is a sample I've put together that would demonstrate its success.

```
set nocount on;
go

-- create the tables
drop table [Car];
drop table [Detail];
drop table [owner]
go

create table dbo.[Owner]
(OwnerID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, OwnerDescription varchar(35) NOT NULL
)

create table dbo.[Detail]
(DetailID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, OwnerID INT NOT NULL
, DetailDescription varchar(35) NOT NULL
)

create table dbo.[Car]
(CarID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, DetailID INT NOT NULL
, CarDescription varchar(35) NOT NULL
)
go

-- create fk constraints
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Detail]
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Detail_Owner FOREIGN KEY (OwnerID)
    REFERENCES dbo.[Owner] (OwnerID) ;

ALTER TABLE dbo.[Car]
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Car_Detail FOREIGN KEY (DetailID)
    REFERENCES dbo.[Detail] (DetailID) ;
GO

-- insert first set of data to consume first identity key values
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Owner] ([OwnerDescription])
VALUES ('Some Owner')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Detail] ([DetailDescription], OwnerID)
VALUES ('Some Detail', 1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Car] ([CarDescription], DetailID)
VALUES ('Some Car', 1)
go

-- examine the data
select * from [Owner]
select * from [Detail]
select * from [Car]
go

-- remove the data with standard delete (because truncate won't work with FKs)
delete from [Car];
delete from [Detail]
delete from [Owner]
go

-- insert second set of data to consume second identity key values
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Owner] ([OwnerDescription])
VALUES ('Some Owner')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Detail] ([DetailDescription], OwnerID)
VALUES ('Some Detail', 2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Car] ([CarDescription], DetailID)
VALUES ('Some Car', 2)
go

-- examine the data
select * from [Owner]
select * from [Detail]
select * from [Car]
go

-- remove the data with standard delete (because truncate won't work with FKs)
delete from [Car];
delete from [Detail]
delete from [Owner]
go

-- reseed the values to 0
dbcc checkident ('Owner', reseed, 0)
dbcc checkident ('Detail', reseed, 0)
dbcc checkident ('Car', reseed, 0)
go

-- reinsert to demonstrate the reseed works
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Owner] ([OwnerDescription])
VALUES ('Some Owner')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Detail] ([DetailDescription], OwnerID)
VALUES ('Some Detail', 1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Car] ([CarDescription], DetailID)
VALUES ('Some Car', 1)
go

-- examine the data
select * from [Owner]
select * from [Detail]
select * from [Car]
go
```